# Echo words not found in string comparison

Tags: php, echo, string-comparison

I have got a variable and an array (can be a variable as well) which need to be compared. I know how to compare two strings, but I don't know how to output the words which haven't been found. Also the words which haven't been found need to be in a variable so that I can use them later on.

```
$mystring = array('Net 40', 'Net 44', 'Priv 40');
$findme   = 'Net 44';
if( strpos($mystring, $findme) !== false ) echo $findme." has been found in the string";
```

**EDIT**
I shall rephrase my question: How to compare two variables and output all words which  haven't been found.

Comment: why is `$mystring` an array?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_diff.asp

Comment: *"I know how to do this"*: your code is not convincing: `strpos` is not how to do that.

Comment: @Huelfe It doesnt have to be it can be a variable as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to find the words that remain after you have successfully matched a word with one in a list:

```
$mystring = array('Net40', 'Net44', 'Priv40');
$findme   = 'Net44';

echo "<br>list of words before: " . implode(",", $mystring);

$mystring = array_diff($mystring, array($findme));

echo "<br>list of words after: " . implode(",", $mystring);
```

Output:

> list of words before: Net40,Net44,Priv40
>   list of words after: Net40,Priv40

Answer (score 0):

strpos check that your second parameter is in the first parameter?
e.g.

> strpos("This is", "is")

this checks that 'is' is in the string or not. If you want to check the result is in array or not please do as follows

```
if(in_array($findme,mystring)) echo $findme." has been found in the string";
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use strpos with an array and a string.

You could make something like this:

```
$mystring = array('Net 40', 'Net 44', 'Priv 40');
$findme   = 'Net 44';

$size = count($mystring)
$notFound = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)
{
    if($mystring[$i] === $findme)
    {
         echo $findme." has been found in the string (actually array)";
    }
    else
    {
        array_push($notFound, $mystring[$i]);
    }
}
```

If mystring is actually supposed to be a string this code has to look a little bit different. I went with what you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with arrays. If your have strings, you can convert them to array with [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

```
 <?php
    $mystring = array('Net40', 'Net44', 'Priv40');
    $findme   = array('Net44');
    $result=array_diff($mystring,$findme);

    //$result is an array of elements that was in $mystring but not in $findme
    print_r($result);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't been found is a little ambiguous, just be careful:

```
<?php

$haystack = array('Net40', 'Net44', 'Priv40');
$needles  = array('Net44', 'NetBsd');

var_dump(array_diff($haystack, $needles));
var_dump(array_diff($needles, $haystack));
var_dump(array_intersect($haystack, $needles));
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Net40' (length=5)
  2 => string 'Priv40' (length=6)

array (size=1)
  1 => string 'NetBsd' (length=6)

array (size=1)
  1 => string 'Net44' (length=5)
```